# Confusion matrix. Percentage of rows and columns

Tags: r, machine-learning, confusion-matrix

I'm creating confusion matrix to sum up results of my model. I see there number of cases (counts). I found also code to calculate share in total of cases (%). But is there a way to show this table as a share in number of cases in columns/rows - marginal distribution in %?

I know there is carrot library and function confusionMatrix. But I would like to have results in a form of a table it is more readable to me (I'm constantly forgetting what is Sensitivity, Specificity etc.).

Code to replicate my table:

```
pred = c('predYes', 'predNo')
real = c('realYes', 'realNo')

sPred<-sample(pred,100, replace=TRUE)
sReal<-sample(real,100, replace=TRUE)

tab<- table(sPred, sReal)
tab
```

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Please add the desired output in code (not description only)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is one of these.

```
prop.table(tab)
prop.table(tab, margin = 1)
prop.table(tab, margin = 2)
```

And you can add the Sums too

```
addmargins(prop.table(tab))
```